# Ruby: Getting Stack level too deep on YAML.load of hash

Tags: ruby, stack, yaml

I'm using YAML in ruby (1.9.3) to dump and load options used by the application.

The path for the file is stored in a constant in a constants.rb file that gets loaded by the main executable for the app.  The options are loaded as a Options class which directly inherits from hash (class Options < Hash).

When I try to load the YAML saved in the options file, I get a SystemStackError: stack too deep (in irb from workspace.rb:80 or from the command line to_ruby.rb:306).

I will put the code for the class below.  Glad to have any comments.  Thanks

```
class Options < Hash
  attr_reader :path, :default_content

  def initialize
    @path = LOG_DIR + '/options.yml'
    @default_content = { auto: true, cbz: true, is_set_up: false }

    if File.exists?( @path )
      self.merge!( YAML.load( File.read( @path ) ) )
    else
      load_default
    end
  end

  def update( key, value )
    if self.has_key?( key )
      self[key] = value
      File.open( @path, 'w' ).write( YAML.dump( self ) )
    else
      puts 'That key does not exist'
    end
  end

  def load_default
    # load default options
    self.merge!( @default_content )
  end
end

Options.new
```

Here is the yaml that is trying to be loaded:

```
--- !ruby/hash:Options
:auto: true
:cbz: true
:is_set_up: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this:

```
--- !ruby/hash:Options
```

Leaving this:

```
:auto: true
:cbz: true
:is_set_up: true
```

That line is a serialized instance of the Options class, and having the Options class load an instance of itself in its initializer is a recipe for stack explosions.

This should get things working:

```
def update( key, value )
  if self.has_key?( key )
    self[key] = value
    File.open( @path, 'w' ) do |f|
      f.write( to_h.to_yaml )
    end
  else
    puts 'That key does not exist'
  end
end
```

`to_h.to_yaml` writes the hash out as YAML.  Also, using the block form of `File.open` ensures the file is closed at the end of the block.

Comment: Ok.  I can't think of a way of doing that (leaving the class as it is) without writing code that stinks.  any suggestion?

Comment: Well YAML.dump is adding it, because you're serializing the class, instead of just saving the contents as a YAML file.  I've updated my answer with a change that should help.

Comment: to_h (I'm actually using to_hash, as to_h gives a NoMethodError for me (I guess a 1.9.3 thing) is not working for me.  to_hash.to_yaml returns the same yaml with the header --- !ruby/hash:Options